# Método para reemplazar (split y replace)

Tags: javascript

Alguien sabe de una librería que me permita usar split en internet explorer 11 o poder cambiar el split y el replace, el Ryarc Campaing Manager presenta problemas en estos dos o de pronto alguna otra solución otro metódo que se pueda usar que no sea split ni replace:

```js
var _from = document.location.pathname.split('/'); // Permite obtener la ruta del archivo actual y convertirla en array separados por "/"
    
_from = _from[_from.length - 1].replace('.html', '').replace('index_', ''); // filtramos el contenido del array y extraemos el nombre del archivo
```

Comment: según yo ambos métodos son soportados en IE6+

Comment: Porque al parecer me presentar problema esa parte del código, se la quito y funciona, el Ryarc no toma ni split ni replace, queda en blanco la pantalla. @LPZadkiel, sabes de pronto de alguna otra forma de hacerlo, algún otro método ?

Comment: quizás el problema está en `document.location` prueba cambiandolo por `window.location`

Comment: Nada, sigue saliendo en blanco. @LPZadkiel

Comment: Buenas. Probando tu codigo en IE5, funciona todo, como lo indicaba @LPZadkiel, estos metodos tienen un soporte nativo

Comment: pregunta: qué es lo que te sigue saliendo en blanco? la variable `_from`? si imprimes `console.log(document.location.pathname)` que es lo que te muestra?

Comment: Lo que me sale en blanco es la pantalla de el televisor, estoy usando Ryarc Campaign Manager y un Player y desde el Ryarc monto el index y un video pero se queda la pantalla de el televisor en blanco, en el pc si funciona todo, esto me sale `Desktop/Pieza-clima/index_3689147.html ` @LPZadkiel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrias crear tus propias funciones algo asi :

**Para el split:**

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
    //recibo el valor del textarea
    var x = $("#data").val();
    //recibo el resultado del split
    alert(miSplit(x, "-"));
});

function miSplit(str, ch) {
    var pos, start = 0, result = [];
    while ((pos = str.indexOf(ch, start)) != -1) {
        result.push(str.substring(start, pos));
        start = pos + 1;
    }
    result.push(str.substr(start));
    return(result);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="data" rows="10">hola-como-estas</textarea>
<button id="test">Validar</button>
```

Se crea una función personalizada donde hago el split envío como parámetros el **String**  y también el **caracter** o **patrón** por el cual se hará dicho split.

Ahora sobre el replace te sugiero revisar esto: [Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285602/5215609)

Suerte..!!